# Relation between ultimate stress and strain

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

I'm comparing the material properties of two polymers A and B and noticed that A has a lower stress at break, but a higher strain at break.

Is it generally true of most polymer materials that when it has a lower stress at break it also has a higher strain at break?

Are stronger (polymer) materials generally more brittle?

Answer (score 0):

These results just mean that A is weaker but more ductile than B; B is stronger but more brittle than A. [Strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_of_materials) and [brittleness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittleness) are properties of all materials, not just polymer materials.

Comment: My question is whether those properties generally go together. Are stronger materials generally more brittle?

Comment: @Angelorf Not always. Biological materials such as tendon can be both strong and ductile. On the other hand, ceramics are both weak and brittle. There is no consistent relationship between the two properties.